# DNX beta8-15530 : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager'

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx, dnvm, coreclr

I have run this command in Package Manager Console to upgrade the dnx.

```
"dnvm upgrade -u default"
```

Once It's get update, I can see(C:\Users\Chandrasekar.dnx\runtimes) the new runtime version as mention below

```
"dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8-15530"
```

I started creating new project in VS2015 --> ASPNET 5 web application it ends up with some errors.

[image]

In output window you can see the error "Could not load *'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager'*", according to this [announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/51) it has been renamed to *'Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling'* so my question is why the new DNX beta 8 version still depends on this removed or renamed DLL *'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager'*?

Output Window Error:

```
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
C:\Users\Chandrasekar\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8-15530\bin\dnx.exe "C:\Users\Chandrasekar\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8-15530\bin\lib\Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager\Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager.dll" restore "C:\Users\Chandrasekar\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DNX8\src\DNX8" -f "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\DNU"
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework)
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Can you please help me to solve this issues? Do I need to update any dlls or software?

Tools:
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.23107.0

Comment: Do you happen to have an environment variable callled `WEBPROJ_ENABLEBETA7RENAMES`?..if so remove it and reload VS and try again and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Same issue as OP, similar logs. I have no WEBPROJ_ENABLEBETA7RENAMES, unless VS2015 is adding it somehow. This errors only within VS2015; it works fine from command line.

Comment: @KiranChalla I haven't added that **environment variable**. I restarted the VS and computer so many times no hopes. Am I missing something else?

Comment: @MattDeKrey Is there any way to solve this issues in VS2015

Comment: Still searching myself, @Chandru! I'll be sure to post an answer if I find one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not using the latest tooling version. Your version is probably 14.0.20711.0 while the latest is 14.0.20723.0.

20711 had a bug because it was trying to load  Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager  which is actually  Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling .

Get the latest version: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48222

See [this](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2371) announcement.

Comment: Make sure the full install instructions are followed - it's two separate installers! (Thanks again, @VictorHurdugaci!)

Comment: Thanks Victor Hurdugaci, I will update the Web Tools 2015 (Beta6) – Visual Studio 2015. How often I have to check and update this tool because until now I didn't get any notification to update my Web tooling? Do I need to register some where to get the notification of new release?

Comment: Thanks Victor. After installing the latest version of Web Tool everything works fine.

Comment: Worked for me too. I used Beta 7. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48738

Answer (score 5):

Let me make this stand out - I tend to forget. Here's Beta 8:

[Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (Beta8) – Visual Studio 2015](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49442)

And a search for all of them - if the name doesn't change, RC1 will show up shortly ;)

[Search results for **Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools** on Microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/result.aspx?q=Microsoft+ASP.NET+and+Web+Tools+2015&form=MSHOME#downloads)

Answer (score 0):

For RC1 there are a lot of choices for the downloads under the [Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC) – Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49959) page , what I was missing was **WebToolsExtensionsVS14.msi**. After installing references got fixed and packages were able to restore.